# How to float or display inline a table

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass

My application shows information about users in a dedicated index page, using unordered list elements. 
Since this information is bare bone, I would like to add more information, such as a list of a user's following and followers besides each user, so I thought of adding two tables beside the basic user details. The code below is an example of what I would like to achieve:

```css
.users {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  }
.users li {
  background-color: green;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 10px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.users div {
  background-color: green;
  width: 200px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<ul class="users">
  <!-- <% @users.each do |user| %> -->
  <li> user.details </li>
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td> follower1 </td>
        <td> follower2 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> follower3 </td>
        <td> follower4 </td>
      </tr>      
    </table>
  </div>
  <!-- <% end %> -->
</ul>
```

However the table does not float or display inline with the `li` block. 
I tried to change the `ul` and `li` tags with a `div` tag, thinking that the problem was due to a div and a table inside a `ul` tag but the result is the same:

```css
.users {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  }
  .details {
    background-color: green;
    width: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 10px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  }
  .following {
    background-color: green;
    width: 200px;
    float: right;
  }
```

```html
<div class="users">
  <!-- <% @users.each do |user| %> -->
  <div class="details"> hello </div>
  <div class="following">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td> follower1 </td>
        <td> follower2 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> follower3 </td>
        <td> follower4 </td>
      </tr>      
    </table>
  </div>
  <!-- <% end %> -->
</div>
```

Using a web inspector it is possible to notice the `div` containing the table outside and below the `ul` (or the `div`) element in which it should instead be enclosed. 
What I would like is to horizontally align side by side these elements, while they result one below the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`UL` can only have `LI` for direct child.**

`.users` details can be wrapped in a tag and `table` `display` can be reset too:

example :

```css
.users {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.users li {
  background-color: green;
  width: 420px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 10px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.users div, .users table {
  background-color: green;
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;/* or inline-table */
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<ul class="users">
  <!-- <% @users.each do |user| %> -->
  <li>
    <div>
    user.details
    </div>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td> follower1 </td>
          <td> follower2 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td> follower3 </td>
          <td> follower4 </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
  </li>
  <!-- <% end %> -->
</ul>
```

that makes 1 li for each users :)